# Shared POSIX objects cleanup on process end / death

Tags: c, unix, synchronization, ipc, posix

Is there any way to perform POSIX shared synchronization objects cleanup especially on process crash? Locked POSIX semaphores unblock is most desired thing but automatically 'collected' queues / shared memory region would be nice too. Another thing to keep eye on is we can't in general use signal handlers because of SIGKILL which cannot be caught.

I see only one alternative: some external daemon which accepts subscriptions and 'keep-alive' requests working as watchdog so not having notifications about some object it could close / unlock object in accordance to registered policy.

Has anyone better alternative / proposition? I never worked seriously with POSIX shared objects before (sockets were enough for all my needs and are much more useful by my opinion) and I did not found any applicable article. I'd gladly use sockets here but can't because of historical reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using semaphores you could use file locking to co-oridinate your processes.  The big advanatge of file locks being that they are released if the process terminates.  You can map each semaphore onto a lock for a byte in a shared file and know that locks will get released on exit; in mosts version of unix the bytes you lock don't even have to exist.  There is code for this in Marc Rochkind's book Advanced Unix Programming 1st edition, don't know if it's in the latest 2nd edition though.

Comment: The book you recommended is really good. lockf() covers at least most dangerous part of original problem (semaphore deadlock)) prototype I built works fine.

Comment: By the way lockf() could be used with third parameter set to 0 (all the file). This way it doesn't require any real byte present. At least on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but another great solution is POSIX robust mutexes. They automatically unlock and enter an "inconsistent flag" state when the owner dies, and the next thread to attempt locking the mutex gets an `EOWNERDEAD` error but succeeds in becoming the new owner of the mutex. It's then able to clean up whatever state the mutex was protecting (which could be in a very bad inconsistent state due to asynchronous termination of the previous owner!) and mark the mutex as consistent again before unlocking it.

See the documentation on robust mutexes here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to work with [signal handlers](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html). Just catch the signals and call the cleanup functions.

But your watchdog daemon has some merits, too. It would surely make the system more simple to understand and manage. To make it more simple to administrate, your application should start the daemon when it's not running and the daemon should be able to clean up any residue from the last crash.

Comment: The problem is we should stay even against SIGKILL. I corrected question based on your answer. What's related to daemon I'd prefer system service implementation so to be able to track dependencies.

Comment: You shouldn't try to trap SIGKILL. If there is a bug in your code, it would be impossible to terminate it. So you don't want that. What you want is to iterate through all resources and check whether they are still in use. Most apps that use SHM offer a tool to clean up all shared resources. I suggest to automate this step.

Comment: Not just "you shouldn't" -- you can't.  http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal "The signals **SIGKILL** and **SIGSTOP** cannot be caught or ignored."

Comment: Sorry, mixed that up with `SIGINT` (aka Ctrl-C) and `SIGTERM` (`kill` command).

Comment: Yes, I understand I can't trap SIGKILL and SIGSTOP I just noted this solution should remain consistent even if someone killed some process with SIGKILL (for example). Though yes, signal handlers should include shared resources deallocation at least for cases we can do it. You are right.

Comment: You must deallocate the resources *at program startup*, too! Sounds insane, I know. The reason is that it's possible to force your process out of the system before you have a chance to clean up. In this case, allocating the SHM during startup will fail (since they are still there). So you must do it twice: At startup, first clean up everything, then allocate it freshly. At shutdown, just deallocate.